# Problem when scaling game screen in Libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

Currently, I'm able to scale the screen by applying this bit of code onto an OrthographicCamera

```
Camera.setToOrtho(true, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
```

But something quite strange is happening with this solution, take a look at this picture of my game below

[image: picture]

Seems fine right? But upon further investigation, many components are rendered off by one pixels, and the tiles all are.

Take a closer look

[image: picture]

I circled a couple of the errors. Note that the shadow of the warrior I circled appears fine for the other warriors. Also keep in mind that everything is rendered at pixel-perfect precision when I disable the scaling.

I actually thought of a possible source for the problem as I'm writing this but I decided to still post this because I would assume somebody else might run into the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It turns out my initial suspicions were right. The SpriteBatch draw method takes floats for the X and Y, so I decided to feed it my positions as is, kept as floats. WRONG. It seems that the SpriteBatch class can't round properly or something because when I cast all of the values to integers and then gave it that, everything turned back to normal and is rendering like it should.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer (after two days or whatever the minimum is).

Comment: Yeah I wanted to mark it but turns out I can't for 2 days and I don't know why

Comment: It's to prevent people just asking/answering their own questions immediately for rep. Please come back and accept it after two days :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't get rep for answering your own question...